# Showing the divergence of a continuously differentiable vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is zero

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, epsilon-delta

> Suppose $F(x)$ is a continuously differentiable (that is, first derivative exist and are continuous) vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfies the bound $$|F(x)| \leq \frac{1}{1 + |x|^3}$$
>   Show that $\int\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \text{div} F dx = 0$.

Attempted proof - Suppose $F(x)$ is a continuously differentiable vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$|F(x)| \leq \frac{1}{1 + |x|^3}$$ From [defintion of vector field](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/122101003/downloads/Lecture-43.pdf) We have $F:D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ where $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. For every $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$, we can write $$F(x) = F_1(x) i + F_2(x) j + F_3(x) k$$ where $ i,j,k$ are the unit vectors. Since $F(x)$ is continuously-differentiable then so are the component functions.

I am a bit lost on trying to go from here. I know that $$\text{div} F = \nabla F = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\cdot \left(F_1,F_2,F_3\right) = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}$$
I think I need to incorporate the bound that $|F(x)|$ in order to show the desired result. Perhaps this is best done using an epsilon-delta sort of proof but I am not sure. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Attempted proof 2 - Let $\{B(0,n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of balls. Since $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable vector field, its components are also continuously differentiable. We know that the surface area of $\partial B(0,n)$ is $4\pi n^2$ and $$|F|\leq \frac{1}{1 + n^3}$$ Thus from the divergent theorem we have $$\int\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\text{div}F dx = \int\int_{B(0,n)}F \times 0 = 0$$

Attempted proof 3 - Let $\{B(0,n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of balls. Since $F(x)$ is a continuously differentiable vector field, its components are also continuously differentiable. We know that the surface area of $\partial B(0,n)$ is $4\pi n^2$ and $$|F|\leq \frac{1}{1 + n^3}$$ Let $S$ be the boundary surface of $B(0,n)$ with positive orientation then from the divergence theorem $$\iint_{S}F dS = \iiint_{B(0,n)}F dB(0,n) $$
Thus if we let $n\to \infty$ we see that $$\iiint_{B(0,n)}F dB(0,n)  = 0$$

Attempted proof 4 - Let $\{B(0,n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of balls. Since $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable vector field, so are its components. Let $S$ be the boundary surface of $B(0,n)$ with positive orientation. We know that the surface area of $\partial B(0,n)$ is $4\pi n^2$ and that 
$$|F|\leq \frac{1}{1 + n^3}$$
Thus if we apply the divergence theorem on the sequence of balls then we have 
$$\Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\text{div}F\,dx\Big| = \lim_n\Big|\int_{B(0,n)}\text{div}F\,dx\Big| = \lim_n\Big|\int_{\partial B(0,n)}F \cdot \nu\,dS\Big| \le \lim_n\frac{4\pi n^2}{1 + n^3} = 0.$$
Thus the result follows.

Comment: In general $F$ may oscillate and $\operatorname{div} F$ may not be a Lebesgue integrable functions, so you need to consider it as an improper integral (i.e. integrate on large balls and take the limit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the divergence theorem on a sequence of balls $B(0,n)$ where $n\to\infty$ and use the bound on $F$ to bound the boundary integral $\int_{\partial B(0,n)}F\cdot \nu\,dS$

Comment: I was just thinking of that a bit, could you perhaps provide a bit more detail on how to show the result?

Comment: The surface area of $\partial B(0,n)$ is $4\pi n^2$ and $|F|\le \frac1{1+n^3}$ so $\int_{\partial B(0,n)}F\cdot \nu dS$ goes to zero.

Comment: Ok, I am going to attempt to proof this with your approach, could you tell me if I am on the right track?

Comment: I tried to prove it based on what you have provided but I am not sure if it is correct or if I am on the right track

Comment: the divergence theorem is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem You should read it first. You have to apply it in $B(0,n)$ not in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I used this following divergence theorem. Let $E$ be a simple solid region and $S$ is the boundary surface of $E$ with positive orientation. Let $F$ be a vector field whose components have continuous first order partial derivatives. Then $$\int \int_{S} F dS = \int\int\int_{E} \text{div} F dV$$

Comment: I am not sure if I did something wrong in my proof, could you help me further?

Comment: It's $\int\int_S F\cdot \nu dS$, where $\nu$ is the normal. Now take $E=B(0,n)$. Off to sleep. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I am sorry I am bit slow with this, but I don't understand what I need to correct in my proof...

Comment: apply the divergence theorem with  $E=B(0,n)$ and then take the limit as $n\to\infty$. What you wrote does not make sense.

Comment: Ok, I made another attempt does it still not make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The third attempt seems to be on the right track, however there is no divergence and it is not entirely clear how you are using the given bound. To expand on Gio67's answer,

$$\Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\text{div}F\,dx\Big| = \lim_n\Big|\int_{B(0,n)}\text{div}F\,dx\Big| = \lim_n\Big|\int_{\partial B(0,n)}F \cdot \nu\,dS\Big| \le \lim_n\frac{4\pi n^2}{1 + n^3} = 0.$$

Comment: Why is there just one single integral? I thought it is three?

Comment: @Wolfy: I'm just using a more compact notation.

Comment: Okay, I made another attempted proof using what you have done as well, does it look correct now?

Comment: @Wolfy: looks good to me.